# how to find a path to go home - algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, path

[image: valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [blogcu.com](http://img2.blogcu.com/images/e/t/k/etkinlik4/clip_image001.jpg))</sub>

Assume there is a rabbit and at position (1,1). Moreover, its home is at position (7,7). How can it reach that position ?

Home positon is not fix place.

Real question, I am trying to solve a problem on a book for exersizing c.**What algorithm should I apply to find solution?**
**Should I use linked list to store data?**

Data is (1,1), (1,2),..., (3,3) ..., (7,7)
Place marked with black shows wall.

Comment: The rabbit lives in its home in the wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  It is the classic go-to algorithm for [path-finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) (that article lists many other algorithms you can consider too).

By using A* you learn an algorithm that you might actually need in your normal programming career later ;)

An example evaluation of a maze similar to that in the question using A*:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/A%2B_Pathfinding_Algorithm.png]

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of search algorithms you can use. The easiest to implement will be either breadth-first search or depth-first search.

Algorithms like A* are likely to be more efficient but are a little harder to code.

Check out the [Wikipedia "Search algorithms"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithms) page. It has links to a number of well-known algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Breadth-first search is always a good one.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/mazesolver.aspx